# php gettext() showing up msgid instead of msgstr

Tags: php, php-gettext

Here is my messages.po file

```
#

msgid "_greet1"
msgstr "Hello"

msgid "_greet2"
msgstr "Bye"
```

I get this po file compiled to mo file using PO Edit, and when I use the mo file inside translation code, I see msgid of the string instead of msgstr. I am using exactly same code written in PHP documentation for gettext.

Any suggestions...

Comment: That means gettext could not locate your translations. Do debug this, we'll need a lot more information...

Comment: I checked the files path, nothing wrong there

Comment: That's not a lot of useful information. If nothing was wrong, you'd see "Hello" instead of "_greet1".

Comment: yup. right, checking deeply...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my folder path was correct too. The reason of the issue was that I was using **'pl_PL'** as locale instead of **'pl_PL.utf8'** (in source code and as a folder name).

**Solution - remember about UTF-8:**

1. Check in console what locales you have and what are their real names: `locale -a`. (In case there is no locale you are interested on you can type: `sudo apt-get install locales-all`)
2. Use correct locale name in your code, for instance:
   `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.utf8');`
3. Change your folder name. Correct path to sample folder with `*.mo` and `*.po` file is: `/var/www/project/locale/pl_PL.utf8/LC_MESSAGES`